# Configuring Mule Port on linux server

Tags: configuration, port, mule

This might be a very simple question for those who are running Mule on linux. I have developed Mule ESB 3.3 app on a windows 8 machine and tested to get desired results by calling my app at

```
    http://localhost:8081/myFlowPath
```

Now I have deployed same app on to a linux machine behind a firewall successfully but am unable to hit it at http://linuxDomainname.com:8081/myFlowPath. The connection is refused. Am I missing something in configuring mule to run on linux?

We are running Mule CE 3.3 standalone as a linux demon. Do I have to explicitly specify something like the port or hostname in the wrapper.conf? Please let me know. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jenni

Comment: If you go on the Linux box, can you hit `http://localhost:8081/myFlowPath`?

Comment: no David when I try it from lynx G http://localhost:8081/myFlowPath it say 'unable to connect to remote host'

Comment: OK so either Mule is not running or the app is not deployed on it.

Comment: Might be an appArmor or SELinux problem.
I would try running: netstat -ltsn, that should print straight from your kernel the address/port combinations actually listened in tcp.

Comment: this is what am doing.. # mule -> then I get the mule starting and deploying statements saying my app is deployed then I Ctrl+Z to break from it.. then.. #lynx -> shift G -> http://localhost:8081/myFlowPath -> hit return/enter to go to tht page... it say unable to connect to host... we have checked the netstat.. 8081 is not showing up in the list :( ... do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Victor as netstat -ltsn is not listing my port do you think we need to configure it to forward requests to myFlowPath or Mule?

Comment: @DavidDossot Does Mule require any additional configuration to listen on that port on the firewall? right now am just using it on my http inbound as host="localhost" port="8081" and path="myFlowPath"... am I missing something?

Comment: @Jeniffer just Crtl-Z will pause your job. You shoud ctrl-z and then type the command "bg". Or use "./mule start".

Comment: Mule doesn't need any extra configuration: whatever port(s) you use in your Mule configs (8081 in your case) will be listened to. You may want to change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in order to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: @DavidDossot we tried to run example apps on CentOS mule and they are working fine and we are able to access the endpoints(ajax/jetty) but my app is using http entry point and not exposing on the port... below is the sample code I used and deployed with below pom.xml.. I have worked with mule apps before but never faced this.. do u see any discrepency here?

Comment: <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xsi:schemalocation="
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd"> 

<description>
    Sample Flows
</description>

<flow name="echo-flow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:9002/echo" />
    <echo-component />
</flow>

Comment: Here's the link to the pom.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271933/exposing-mule-http-inbound-endpoint/15276743?noredirect=1#15276743

Comment: @DavidDossot I worked with apps where I was using custome name to my flow xml and not mule-config.xml.. but do u think that is the issue? do I have to echange my flow xml name to mule-config.xml?

Comment: @Jennifer your config _have_ to be named mule-config.xml unless you changed the config.resources property in your mule-deploy.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure HTTP Listener host to 0.0.0.0 (change from localhost). 
Check log mule at HOME_MULE/logs/mule.log or webservice.log
After deploy your app you must have in HOME_MULE/apps/nameofyourapp/webservice.xml (or filename defined in "config.resources" in file mule-deploy.properties) this:

It work for me. I deploying my mule apps on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Mule ESB 3.8.1.

If this not work, it mean that you blocked that port (8081) on this machine (or firewall). Check iptables or another your 3th-party firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Mule handle it easily by using the application properties. Create property files for each environment `local|develop|prod`.

**local.properties**

api.host=0.0.0.0

api.port=8080

**prod.properties**

api.host=127.0.0.1

api.port=9090

Read more about the mule service configuration management at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-properties.